# FlaskForm + Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps, flask

I'm new with Javascript and stuck with google Waypoints Directions

How to pass data from FlaskForm in `<select multiple id="waypoints">` ? to make it work. `{{form.add_1.data}}` doesn't work.

app.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, url_for
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, SubmitField

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['SECRET_KEY']='secret'

class TestForm(FlaskForm):
    start = StringField()
    add_1 = StringField()
    end = StringField()
    submit = SubmitField()

@app.route('/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def index():
    form = TestForm()
    return render_template ('city.html', form=form)


if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, port=8000)
```

template

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Waypoints in Directions</title>
    <style>
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
   <div class="container">
        <form action="" method="post">
        {{form.start}}
        {{form.add_1}}
          {{form.end}}


          {{form.submit()}}
        </form>
      </div>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <div id="right-panel">
    <div>
    <b>Start</b>

    <select id="start">
      <option value="{{form.start.data}}">{{form.start.data}}</option>
      <option value="Boston, MA">Boston, MA</option>
      <option value="New York, NY">New York, NY</option>
      <option value="Miami, FL">Miami, FL</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <b>Waypoints:</b> <br>
    <i>(Ctrl+Click or Cmd+Click for multiple selection)</i> <br>
    <select multiple id="waypoints">
      <option value="{{form.add_1.data}}">{{form.add_1.data}}</option>
      <option value="toronto, ont">Toronto, ONT</option>
      <option value="chicago, il">Chicago</option>
      <option value="winnipeg, mb">Winnipeg</option>
      <option value="fargo, nd">Fargo</option>
      <option value="calgary, ab">Calgary</option>
      <option value="spokane, wa">Spokane</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <b>End:</b>
    <select id="end">
      <option value="{{form.end.data}}">{{form.end.data}}</option>
      <option value="Seattle, WA">Seattle, WA</option>
      <option value="San Francisco, CA">San Francisco, CA</option>
      <option value="Los Angeles, CA">Los Angeles, CA</option>
    </select>
    <br>
      <input type="submit" id="submit">
    </div>
    <div id="directions-panel"></div>
    </div>
    <script>
      function initMap() {
        var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
        var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 6,
          center: {lat: 41.85, lng: -87.65}
        });
        directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

        document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', function() {
          calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay);
        });
      }

      function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay) {
        var waypts = [];
        var checkboxArray = document.getElementById('waypoints');
        for (var i = 0; i < checkboxArray.length; i++) {
          if (checkboxArray.options[i].selected) {
            waypts.push({
              location: checkboxArray[i].value,
              stopover: true
            });
          }
        }

        directionsService.route({
          origin: document.getElementById('start').value,
          destination: document.getElementById('end').value,
          waypoints: waypts,
          optimizeWaypoints: true,
          travelMode: 'DRIVING'
        }, function(response, status) {
          if (status === 'OK') {
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
            var route = response.routes[0];
            var summaryPanel = document.getElementById('directions-panel');
            summaryPanel.innerHTML = '';
            // For each route, display summary information.
            for (var i = 0; i < route.legs.length; i++) {
              var routeSegment = i + 1;
              summaryPanel.innerHTML += '<b>Route Segment: ' + routeSegment +
                  '</b><br>';
              summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[i].start_address + ' to ';
              summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[i].end_address + '<br>';
              summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[i].distance.text + '<br><br>';
            }
          } else {
            window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
          }
        });
      }
    </script>
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MYAPIKEY&callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```